# LIMIT of $\frac{x}{x+x^x}$ when x approaches zero

Tags: calculus

What is the limit of the following function: 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x+x^x}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use: $\displaystyle~0\leq\frac{x}{x+x^x}\leq \frac{x}{x+\min x^x}$ , $~~\min x^x > 0 ~~ => ~~$ the limit is $~0~~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide top and bottom by $x,$ to get $$\frac{1}{1+x^{x-1}}.$$

Now, you only need to find the limit of $x^{x-1}$ as $x$ becomes evanescent from above. We write this as $$e^{\log x^{x-1}},$$ and then we only need evaluate the limit of $\log x^{x-1},$ which we may write as $$(x-1)\log x,$$ which is clearly $+\infty.$ Thus, the expression goes to $$\frac{1}{+\infty},$$ or $0.$

Comment: is it +∞ or -∞ in the denominator, because when x approaches zero (x-1)logx approaches (0-1)log0 which give -∞???

Comment: @QaSim It is $+\infty$ because $(0-1)\log 0=-(-\infty).$

Answer (score 0):

The hint you need is the limit 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log x  = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log x}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} (-x) = 0
$$
by L'Hospital's rule. Use it to get the limit in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$x^x=e^{x \log x}\to e^0=1$$

indeed by $y=\frac1x \to \infty$

$$x \log x=-\frac{\log y}{y}\to 0$$